Webex SDK with Vue3
i am trying to use webex javascript sdk with my vue3 project but not able to use it correctly while it is running correctly while using vanila javascript but not with vue3.
here is my code:
        this.callings = await Calling.init({ webexConfig, callingConfig });
        // await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));
        this.callings.on("ready", async () => {

            await this.callings.register();
            console.log('ddd', this.callings.callingClient.getLines());
            this.line = Object.values(this.callings.callingClient.getLines())[0];
            this.line.on("registered", () => console.log("Line registered"));
        });
    },

i tried to contact with support but they dont know vue3 so did not able to solve my problem.

"here is my code" ... what part of that code has the issue?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

webex sdk is not able to find Calling export and not initializing call instead keep giving me errors.
